# Telegram URL on a Webview (share on Telegram app link)

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, telegram

I'm working on a web page that will opens in an Android Webview. I need to share some content with Telegram application, so I want to launch Telegram app (if it's installed) when user clicked on a button.

I found same functionality for sending email with `mailto:?subject=Hi%20there&body=Hello%20there` or share in whatsapp with `whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20there` and used them in web page like below:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20there"></a>
```

Is there any way to call Telegram application?

**Answer:**

```
tg:msg?text=Hello%20there

<a href="tg:msg?text=Hello%20there"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tg:` protocol, but the better way is use `t.me` link.

For instance: https://t.me/SeanChannel will redirect to

```
tg:resolve?domain=SeanChannel
```

Comment: You helps me to find `tg` namespace! I correct answer to my question is `tg:msg?text=Hello%20there`